# Modal doesn't display data fetched by axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm new to Vue and trying to display data fetched by axios to a modal.
The problem is the modal doesn't display the data.
I've checked the birthday variable and it does contain the data.

**Template**

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="birthdayModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content mx-auto text-center bg-danger text-warning">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>
          HAPPY
          <i class="fa-fw fas fa-birthday-cake"></i> BIRTHDAY!
        </h1>
        <img
          :src="'/img/members/' +birthday.dob"
          width="250px"
          height="250px"
          class="img img-responsive"
        />
        <h3 class="mt-3">{{birthday.alias_name}}</h3>
        <h3>{{birthday.dob}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      birthday: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    birthdayModal() {
      axios
        .get('api/members/birthday')
        .then(res => (this.birthday = res.data))
        .then($('#birthdayModal').modal('show'))
      console.log('Birthday Data: ', this.birthday)
    },
  },
  created() {},
  mounted() {
    this.birthdayModal()
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  },
}
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function birthday()
{   
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $member = Member::whereMonth('dob', '=', $date->month)->whereDay('dob', '=', $date->day)->get();
    return $member;
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need two `.then()` chain, doing stuff inside first should suffice. 2. Try putting a `v-if='birthday.length >0'` on modal body. 3. Mixing jQuery with vue is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow HelloWorld1014!

I had a similar problem in my project, where datepicker.js wouldn't load in my modal. I resolved this by re-initializing the datepicker on modal shown [event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/).

I did something like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('.date').datepicker();
});
```

Hope that this can lead you in right direction.

Comment: thanks for the greetings but i'm not using datepicker.js

Comment: I know, I just gave you an example of how I resolved my problem. Try the same but with your .js script

Answer (score 0):

As @ambianBeing pointed out, you don't need two `.then(...)`. Instead, you should create another method, and call it in your first `.then(...)`.

For example:

```
    export default {
            data(){
                return{
                    birthday:[],
                }
            },
            methods:{
                birthdayModal(){
                     axios.get('api/members/birthday').then(res=>this.parseAndDisplay(res));
                },
                parseAndDisplay(result){
                     this.birthday = result.data;
                     $('#birthdayModal').modal('show'));
                     console.log("Birthday Data: ", this.birthday);
                }
            },
            created(){
            },
            mounted() {
                this.birthdayModal();
                console.log('Component mounted.')
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.